lint-stage config for multi nested folder
My psudo folder structure.
/
/Dir1/CsFiles/A.cs
/Dir2/SomeFunc/B.cs
/Dir3/Controllers/Web.cs
/Dir3/ClientApp/lint-stage.config.cjs

my lint-stage config
module.exports = {
  '../../**/*.cs': (filenames) => {
    return [
      `dotnet csharpier ${filenames.map(filename => `"${filename}"`).join(" ")}`,
    ];
  },

  '**/*.{ts,tsx}': (filenames) => {
    return [
      'npm run type:check',
      `eslint ${filenames.map(filename => `"${filename}"`).join(" ")} --fix --color`,
    ];
  },

  '**/*.{scss,css}': (filenames) => {
    return [
      `prettier ${filenames.map(filename => `"${filename}"`).join(" ")} --write`,
    ];
  },
};

it does not match any cs files. What should I change so lint-stage can match any cs files in any directory?
